# Accept two different model instances as a function argument php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm writing a helper function to check whether any address information is present in my database by checking if any of the relevant fields don't equal null.

So, I have two models which I need to accept in the function as an argument.

- App\Customer
- App\Supplier

The variable passed can be either one.

For a function that should only accept one kind of model, I can just do this:

```
function check_for_address_info(App\Customer $customer) {
    // other unrelated stuff
}
```

Is there a way to accept both models, or do I have to manually check it in the function by doing something like this:

```
function check_for_address_info($param) {
  if(!is_a($param, 'App\Customer' || !is_a($param, 'App\Supplier')) {
    // not an instance of either model
    return false;
  }

  // do stuff as normal
}
```

Any ideas on how to accept two different models as a function argument?

I'm on Laravel 5.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two approaches, if it makes sense inheritance wise, you can extend a parent model and declare it as the type of the parameter. This will be checked on run time and provide an error if you pass the wrong type to the method.

```
public class Profile extends Model {
}

public class Customer extends Profile {
}

public class Supplier extends Profile {
}

function check_for_address_info(App\Profile $customerOrSupplier) {
}
```

In weak typed languages, it is common to have parameters that are generic. The way `PHP` solve this problem, is you can declare it in `PHP` Doc blocks. This will not check types on run time and is mostly for typehinting, documentation and static analysis tools.

```
/**
 * @parameter \App\Customer|\App\Supplier $customerOrSupplier
 **/
function check_for_address_info($customerOrSupplier) {
}
```

Comment: Extending the classes makes the most sense and seems the most logical. Thanks.